# Android studio EditText clickable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a simple question. I'm creating a game which players have to set their nick names in EditText. When I start an intent to the activity in which they have to put their names in, the Keyboard pops up, like this:

This is my EditText:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Nickname"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/etNickName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Is there any way that the keyboard will not pop up right away when the activity starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to your root layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue_dark"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        .
        .
        .
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped

Comment: you're welcome...accept answer

Answer (score 1):

just write this in you Manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```